# Check specific custom attribute from the variation of a WooCommerce variable product

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, product-variations

In WooCommerce, I have a `Variable Product` type product with `ID 1010`. This product has an attribute **Name:** "`book terms`" with two defined product types **Value(s)**:

- "`phys (best)`"
- "`version (limit)`"

I want to write a code in `function.php` that when a customer enters the current order page they have purchased at `/my-account/view-order/` in their user panel (Order details), the same page where the product is purchased, the product description is displayed on that page (for example, if the order number is 911, the address will be `/my-account/view-order/911/`).

First, it should be checked whether the current order that the customer is in the details page of has a product with `ID 1010`. If the product with `ID 1010` is in this order, it should be checked which attributes of this product ("`phys (best)`" and "`version (limit)`") have been purchased and the value of these attributes should be displayed along with the current order number. I should also be able to check the values inside these attributes ("`phys (best)`" and "`version (limit)"`) using a conditional statement.

The customer may have purchased more than one copy of this product with `ID 1010`, so these items should be separated from each other (for example, the customer may have purchased 10 copies of this book or product with `ID 1010`, of which 2 copies are "`version (limit)`", 5 copies are "`phys (best)`" and 3 copies are both "`phys (best)" and "version (limit)`" together).

The customer may have purchased both attributes of the product with `ID 1010` or only one of them, so this should also be separated.

I want all these conditions to be done in the following source code and in `<h1>THIS SECTION</h1>`:

```
function detect_book_type($productId){
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    $current_user_email = $current_user->user_email;

    switch($productId):
        <?php case "1": ?>
            <label>product number 1 : </label>
            <input type="text" value="<?php echo something; ?>" readonly>
        <?php break; ?>

        <?php case "2": ?>
            <label>product number 2 : </label>
            <input type="text" value="<?php echo something; ?>" readonly>
        <?php break; ?>
        
        <?php case "1010": ?>
            <label>Book address is : </label>
            <h1>THIS SECTION</h1>
        <?php break; ?>
        
        <?php default : ?>
        <p>There seems to be a problem...!</p>
    <?php endswitch;
}
```

###### Attributes Settings:

[image: Attributes]

###### Variations Settings:

[image: Variations]

---

###### Error screenshot

[image: my error image]

**I wrote the following source code, but it has two problems:**

- If a customer purchases both attributes of a product with `ID 1010` (i.e., "`phys (best)`" and "`version (limit)`"), only the values related to "`phys (best)`" are displayed repeatedly on the `view-order` page of their account. Instead of showing both attributes, only one attribute is displayed twice.
- In the line `$product_variation_id = $item->get_variation_id();`, when I **`print_r`** the value of `$product_variation_id`, it always contains only one value (only one of the two values "`phys (best)`" and "`version (limit)`"). Even though an order may include product 1010 with two attributes, only one value is stored in this variable!

```
function detect_book_type($productId){
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    $current_user_email = $current_user->user_email;
    
    switch($productId):
        <?php case "1": ?>
            <label>product number 1 : </label>
            <input type="text" value="<?php echo something; ?>" readonly>
        <?php break; ?>
        
        <?php case "2": ?>
            <label>product number 2 : </label>
            <input type="text" value="<?php echo something; ?>" readonly>
        <?php break; ?>
        
        <?php case "1010": ?>
            <label>Book address is : </label>
            <h1>THIS SECTION</h1>
            <?php
                
                $current_order_id = get_query_var('view-order');
                $order = wc_get_order( $current_order_id );
                $items = $order->get_items();
                
                $product_exists = false;
                $product_variation_id = null;
                
                foreach ( $items as $item ) {
                    $product_id = $item->get_product_id();
                    
                    if ( $product_id == 1010 ) {
                        $product_exists = true;
                        $product_variation_id = $item->get_variation_id();
                        break;
                    }
                }
                
                if ( $product_exists ) {

                    $product_attributes = wc_get_product_variation_attributes( $product_variation_id );

                    $product_attributes = $product_attributes['attribute_book-terms'];
                    
                    if ( $product_attributes === "phys (best)" ) {
                        $run_phys_books_best = run_phys_books_func();
                        ?>
                            <label>sample text phys:</label>
                            <input type="text" value="<?php echo $run_phys_books_best; ?>" readonly>
                        <?php
                    }
                    elseif ( $product_attributes === "version (limit)" ) {
                        $run_limited_version = run_limit_func();
                        ?>
                            <label>sample text limit:</label>
                            <input type="text" value="<?php echo $run_limited_version; ?>" readonly>
                        <?php
                    }
                    elseif ( ($product_attributes === "phys (best)" ) && ( $product_attributes === "version (limit)") ) {
                        if ( $product_attributes === "phys (best)" ) {
                            $run_phys_books_best = run_phys_books_func();
                            ?>
                                <label>sample text phys:</label>
                                <input type="text" value="<?php echo $run_phys_books_best; ?>" readonly>
                            <?php
                        }
                        if ( $product_attributes === "version (limit)" ) {
                            $run_limited_version = run_limit_func();
                            ?>
                                <label>sample text limit:</label>
                                <input type="text" value="<?php echo $run_limited_version; ?>" readonly>
                            <?php
                        }
                    }
    
                } else {
                    echo 'nothing!';
                }

            ?>
        <?php break; ?>
        
        <?php default : ?>
        <p>There seems to be a problem...!</p>
    <?php endswitch;
}
```

Comment: You get this error because the order ID is not defined (or not always defined) via `$order_id = get_query_var('order-id');`, then `$order` variable is false instead of being the WC_Order object.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec, Thank you for your guidance. I have now updated and corrected my source code, but I encountered two problems that I explained in my question, and in addition, I have attached an image of my issue. Thank you again for your kind help.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec, Perfect, I have added the requested images to my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some mistakes in your code, try the following revised function code:

```php
function detect_book_type( $product_id ){
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    $current_user_email = $current_user->user_email;

    switch( $product_id ):
        case '1': 
            printf('<label>%s : </label>
            <input type="text" value="%s" readonly>', 
            __('product number 1'), __('something (product 1)') );
            break;

        case '2':
            printf('<label>%s : </label>
            <input type="text" value="%s" readonly>', 
            __('product number 2'), __('something (product 2)') );
            break;
        
        case '1010':
            printf('<label>%s : </label><h1>%s</h1>', 
            __('Book address is'), __('THIS SECTION') );

            $order_id = absint( get_query_var('view-order') );
            $order    = wc_get_order( $order_id );

            $order_items = is_a($order, 'WC_Order') ? $order->get_items() : array();

            foreach ( $order_items as $item ) {
                if ( $item->get_product_id() != $product_id ) 
                    continue;

                $variation = $item->get_product();
                    
                switch( $variation->get_attribute('book terms') ):
                    case 'phys (best)': 
                        printf('<label>%s:</label>
                        <input type="text" value="%s" readonly>', 
                        __('sample text phys'), run_phys_books_func() );
                        break;
                    
                    case 'version (limit)':
                        printf('<label>%s:</label>
                        <input type="text" value="%s" readonly>', 
                        __('sample text limit'), run_limit_func() );
                        break;
                endswitch;
                break; // <== Added (update)
            }
            break;
    endswitch;
}
```

It should work.

Comment: Great, the only problem is that in products that have two attributes, each purchase is displayed against the other attribute purchase. I have shown this problem in the image.

[link](https://imgtr.ee/images/2024/02/04/fc5cbcba8cd722f3f704812e7540764f.png)
[link](https://i.postimg.cc/pTcTv3xJ/2.png)

Comment: @John I have updated my code adding a `break;` just after the 2nd `endswitch`.

Comment: Thank you. It correctly shows only one item for each product, but it only shows the first option, "phys (best)," for both products with different attributes. For the second product with a different attribute, it still shows the same "phys (best)."
[image my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QMrIC.png)

Comment: @John The question Here on the start was about an error related to `$order->get_item()`, so this is solved and much more… Now you should ask a new Question providing all the related code and details where detect_book_type() function is used, with explanations…

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77939383/check-specific-custom-attribute-from-the-variation-of-a-woocommerce-variable-pro

Thanks, i added new Question