# Check specific custom attribute from the variation of a WooCommerce variable product - problem with multiple attributes

Tags: woocommerce

I have reached the answer I wanted in my previous question ([Check specific custom attribute from the variation of a WooCommerce variable product](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77932152/check-specific-custom-attribute-from-the-variation-of-a-woocommerce-variable-pro)), but have encountered a new problem. The problem is that if a **product with ID 1010**, which has multiple attributes, is purchased by a customer, all the attributes (in this example, two attributes) in an order will repeat the first attribute for other products with different attributes.

Let me give an example:
The **product with ID 1010** has two attributes with values `phys (best)` and `version (limit)`.
If a customer purchases the **product with ID 1010** and only one of these two attributes (`phys (best)` or `version (limit)`), there is no problem and it is completely correct. However, if the customer purchases both attribute values (`phys (best)` and `version (limit)`) in one order, the corresponding codes for each product with its own attribute should be displayed. But this is not the case, and repetitive codes are displayed for all products.

However, if I do not include the "`break;`" for updating the answer to my question, the codes are displayed correctly, but all attributes are displayed against all products, as can be seen in the images and descriptions of my previous question.

**image one (with use break; // <== Added (update)):**
[image: image one]
**image two (without use break; // <== Added (update)):**
[image: image two]

```
function detect_book_type( $product_id ){
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    $current_user_email = $current_user->user_email;

    switch( $product_id ):
        case '1': 
            printf('<label>%s : </label>
            <input type="text" value="%s" readonly>', 
            __('product number 1'), __('something (product 1)') );
            break;

        case '2':
            printf('<label>%s : </label>
            <input type="text" value="%s" readonly>', 
            __('product number 2'), __('something (product 2)') );
            break;
        
        case '1010':
            printf('<label>%s : </label><h1>%s</h1>', 
            __('Book address is'), __('THIS SECTION') );

            $order_id = absint( get_query_var('view-order') );
            $order    = wc_get_order( $order_id );

            $order_items = is_a($order, 'WC_Order') ? $order->get_items() : array();

            foreach ( $order_items as $item ) {
                if ( $item->get_product_id() != $product_id ) 
                    continue;

                $variation = $item->get_product();
                    
                switch( $variation->get_attribute('book terms') ):
                    case 'phys (best)': 
                        printf('<label>%s:</label>
                        <input type="text" value="%s" readonly>', 
                        __('sample text phys'), run_phys_books_func() );
                        break;
                    
                    case 'version (limit)':
                        printf('<label>%s:</label>
                        <input type="text" value="%s" readonly>', 
                        __('sample text limit'), run_limit_func() );
                        break;
                endswitch;
                **break; // <== Added (update)**
            }
            break;
    endswitch;
}
```

**These two functions precisely address the issue I have in the question.

I hope my question is comprehensive and that I have been able to explain it well.**

```
function run_phys_books_func() {

    if ($booooooks_item = get_user_meta(get_current_user_id(), 'phys (best)', true)) {
        $book_result = $booooooks_item;
    } else {
        // something...

        $book_result = 'dummy_data : phys (best)';

        update_user_meta(get_current_user_id(), 'phys (best)', $book_result);
    }

    return $book_result;
}

function run_limit_func() {
    
    if ($booooooks_item = get_user_meta(get_current_user_id(), 'version (limit)', true)) {
        $book_result = $booooooks_item;
    } else {
        // something...

        $book_result = 'dummy_data';

        update_user_meta(get_current_user_id(), 'version (limit) : version (limit)', $book_result);
    }

    return $book_result;
}
```

Comment: In this example, which I have attached its images to my question, product 1010 with the attribute value of `phys (best)` is the first product of this order. Therefore, for other products of this order, the codes and commands related to `phys (best)` are executed and repeated.

Comment: Provide the code where you are using detect_book_type() function in your question. Also provide the code of missing run_phys_books_func() and run_limit_func() functions... Your related code is incomplete, not testable and the issue is not reproducible. See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @LoicTheAztec, Yes, of course. All of these source codes are executed in a file included (require_once) in `function.php`.

The `detect_book_type()` function is exactly the same function with some changes in the classes of HTML elements and other cases for other products. Nothing else is added to this part of the source code of the **1010** switch, and these are exactly the same codes.

Regarding the functions `run_phys_books_func()` and `run_limit_func()`, here are the two functions, both of which are written below in a summarized form with the extra codes removed:

Comment: Don't add code as a comment, edit your question (and delete those comments please)… Sorry but read carefully  [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) as your code is not testable, and your issue is not reproducible.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec, I added my functions and change source code